# Add margin bottom to last ListView item in NativeScript

Tags: listview, nativescript

What I'm trying to achieve is allow a ListView to scroll past the last item in the list, in order to clear a floating button on the bottom of the list view:

[image]

I did this for now by adding padding to the last item in the list, so list will scroll past the last item:

[image]

While this looks ok, the problem is that the user can tap on the blank space on the bottom of the list:

[image]

Adding margin to the last element doesn't seem to work.

Any idea how can I achieve this behavior without the issues. For a working example, please see the Gmail Android app.

PS: I don't want to migrate to the RadListView, if that would fix the issue, as RadListView has some performance penalties :(

Comment: Wrap it in a StackLayout and add a margin for that ;)

Comment: You may include a empty footer with padding.

Comment: @Peter That doesn't solve my problem: the StackLayout is still clickable

Comment: @Manoj How do you do that with ListView ?

Comment: That's my bad, I always use RadListView. ListView doesn't have one, you might have to do it natively.

Comment: why is that problem the stacklayout container is clickable (tap)? Every element on your screen is clickable since they're on the screen :))

Comment: You could use DockLayout, and have the plus positioned under the entries if there's only a few, or at the bottom the screen if there's more than a screen's worth.

Comment: @Peter Because I don't want the user to be able to access the last item in the list by tapping the space bellow the list

Comment: If you wrap the whole thing in a StackLayout and add bottom margin it won't trigger clicking the last item, that's another item outside of the listview

Comment: @Peter I don't want to move the whole list above the button, I want to be able to scroll the list paste the last item, so that the last item can be seen above the button. This way I don't loose that screen real-estate to the floating button.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what I'm suggesting is exactly this what you're talking about. If you add a margin bottom outside of the listview if you add a new item, it will appear above the + button as a list item. Pls create a sample project here and we can help: https://play.nativescript.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a job for...**nsTemplateKey**

```
<ListView [items]="items" class="list-group" [itemTemplateSelector]="templateSelector" row="0">
<ng-template nsTemplateKey="regular" let-item="item" let-i="index">
    <GridLayout (tap)="regularAction()">
        <Label [text]="item.name" backgroundColor="red" color="white"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
</ng-template>

<ng-template nsTemplateKey="margin" let-item="item" let-i="index">
    <GridLayout marginBottom="50" rows="auto, *">
        <Label row="0" (tap)="innerClick()" [text]="item.name" backgroundColor="green" color="yellow"></Label>
        <Label row="1"><Label>
    </GridLayout>
</ng-template>
```

Now we just require the last item to have special params and options:

```
templateSelector(item, index: number, items: any) {
    return index < items.length -1 ? "regular" : "margin";
}
```

I think this is a nice way to do this, now you can also use **isPassThroughParentEnabled** and **isUserInteractionEnabled** with your current code, you will have to play a lil bit with all this options and find the best solution for you, cheers.

```
<ListView [items]="items" class="list-group" 
      backgroundColor="red" separatorColor="blue">
<ng-template let-item="item">
    <GridLayout height="60" isPassThroughParentEnabled="!isLast">
        <Label (tap)="action" isUserInteractionEnabled="!isLast"[text]="item.name" class="list-group-item" color="white"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
</ng-template>
```